# color item listview with action bar contextual

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I've a ListView and when i click on an item i would like that it's colored in a determinate color because when i click on an item compairs the Contextual Action Bar, Why do people have to see which items on the list were selected. I wrote this code.

```
    private void onListItemSelect(int position) {
        adapter.toggleSelection(position);
        boolean hasCheckedItems = adapter.getSelectedCount() > 0;

        if (hasCheckedItems && mActionMode == null)
            // there are some selected items, start the actionMode
            mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(new ActionModeCallback());

        else if (!hasCheckedItems && mActionMode != null)
            // there no selected items, finish the actionMode
            mActionMode.finish();

        if (mActionMode != null)
            mActionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(adapter.getSelectedCount()) + " selezionati");
    }

    private class ActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // inflate contextual menu
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_action_bar, menu);


            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item1:

                item.setIcon(R.drawable.delete_pressed);
                //mode.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // remove selection
            adapter.removeSelection();
            mActionMode = null;
        }
    }

applicationListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            { 
                adapter.isSelected(true, view);
                onListItemSelect(position);

            }

    });
```

In my adapter i've

```
 public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
        if (value)
            mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
        else
            mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void toggleSelection(int position) {
        selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
    }

    public int getSelectedCount() {
        return mSelectedItemsIds.size();
    }

    public void removeSelection() {
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void isChecked(boolean checked, View v) {
        if(checked) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }
        else {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I click on the item are colored correctly and appears contextual action bar and so far all is well. The problem is that the elements remain colored even when there is no longer the contextual action bar. I wish that when there were restored to their normal color, then clear. How can I do?